# Symfony2.1: Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I used the ["Using a traditional login form"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form) tutorial from symfony.com to authentificate my users. With a simple http auth it works great.

After the login was submitted I get this Exception:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you
>   forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

Well, in the tutorial I read:

> You will not need to implement a controller for the /login_check URL as the firewall will automatically catch and process any form submitted to this URL.

I defined the routes and set the firewall settings:

**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    backend:
        pattern:    ^/backend
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: entity
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            #use_forward: true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

**routing.yml**

```
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: VitaSecurityBundle:Default:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check
logout:
    pattern:   /logout
```

Comment: Is the login form only meant to allow access to the backend ?

Comment: Yes, this is only for backend user

Comment: Nice solution. I had the exact same problem. You should post your solution as an answer an accept it. than it's easier to find. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I found the solution to my problem

I added the /backend prefix to my paths, removed the 'anonymous: ~' line and commented out the ACL for backend.

**security.yml**

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/backend/login$
        anonymous:  ~
    backend:
        pattern:    ^/backend
        form_login:
            provider: entity
            login_path: /backend/login
            check_path: /backend/login_check
            #use_forward: true
        logout:
            path:   /backend/logout
            target: /

access_control:
    #- { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**routing.yml**

```
login:
    pattern:   /backend/login
    defaults:  { _controller: VitaSecurityBundle:Default:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /backend/login_check
logout:
    pattern:   /backend/logout
```

Answer (score 18):

The problem you are having is described here:

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html, section "Avoid Common Pitfalls"

> 1. Be sure `/login_check` is behind a firewall
>      Next, make sure that your check_path URL (e.g. /login_check) is behind the firewall you're using for your form login (in this example, the single firewall matches all URLs, including /login_check). If /login_check doesn't match any firewall, you'll receive a Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check" exception.

In this example, your pattern specifies a prefix of /backend for secured paths. To work, your login check should be behind this same firewall.

So, to match the pattern which you have specified in your firewall, put login_check on a url path like this: /backend/login_check

Comment: good catch. Christophe Coevoet from a google groups post also said: "The security listeners are only attached when the request matches the 
pattern of the firewall. So you need to use an url of the form 
/admin/logout to be in the scope of the listener."

Comment: Newbie mistake/gotcha: Note that if you have ^/ and ^/admin and need two login forms, the more specific pattern (^/admin) must be above the more general pattern ^/ in the file or else it won't take precedence since ^/ can still match ^/admin - at least, that's what finally made this work in my app where I have the need for two login forms and already had a ^/ pattern in security.yml and I didn't realize that's how yml deals with regex precedence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem also tends to happen when you have two firewall with the same pattern. For example:

```
....
 backend:
            pattern:        ^/*
....
 frontend:
            pattern:        ^/*
```

You must change one of the two as follows:

```
....
 backend:
            pattern:        ^/(administrador|backend)/*
....
frontend:
            pattern:        ^/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code I used in a real-life project:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/cmd
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /cmd/login_check
            login_path: /cmd/login
        remember_me:
            always_remember_me: true
            key:      "%secret%"
            path:     /cmd
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
        logout:
            path:   /cmd/logout
            target: /

    admin:
        pattern: ^/admin
        http_basic:
            realm: "Administration"

    free_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
```

In my case, only the /cmd/ part is secured, the /admin/ part is also secured, but with HTTP security.

Maybe you should try:
security.yml

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    backend:
        pattern:    ^/backend
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: entity
            login_path: /backend/login
            check_path: /backend/login_check
            #use_forward: true
        logout:
            path:   /backend/logout
            target: /
```

and as of routing.yml:

```
login:
    pattern:   /backend/login
    defaults:  { _controller: VitaSecurityBundle:Default:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /backend/login_check
logout:
    pattern:   /backend/logout
```

I think your problem might come from the fact security is not activated in your / part (the pattern of your secured area is ^/backend)

Comment: Thanks! I tried a little bit and have found a solution (i edit my inital post)

Answer (score 0):

This was not workging for me and I try something else :

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:    ^/(_profiler|_wdt|css|js)
        security:   false

    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern: /(admin/.*|login_check)
        provider: in_memory
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            default_target_path: /admin
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

With the following explanation, simpler than the explanation from zabojad.
The important thing is to put the login_check route inside a firewall and to let the login outside. With a or pattern you can succeed.

Max