# Symfony 2.1 security login check error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I am building the login form as shown in symfony 2.1 documentation.  i am doing the same thing.
i got success in simple authorization but when i create the simple login form i gets   login_check route not found.
  if i put login_check route then i got login_check error.
Documentation says nothing about this. 
My security.yml is

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
  providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        anonymous: false
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path:            /admin/content/index
            target_path_parameter:          _target_path
            use_referer:                    false
            username_parameter:             _username
            password_parameter:             _password
            csrf_parameter:                 login[_token]
        logout: 
            path: /admin/logout
            target: /login
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

and routing.yml is

```
login:
pattern:  /login
defaults: { _controller: AcmeTaskBundle:Default:login}

login_check:
pattern: /login_check        
defaults: { _controller: AcmeTaskBundle:Default:loginCheck}

logout:
pattern: /admin/logout
defaults: { _controller: AcmeTaskBundle:Default:logout}
content_index:
pattern: /admin/content/index
defaults: { _controller: AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index }
```

my controller login action is

```
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Product;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\CmsContentMst;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\CmsSectionsMst;

// use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\ProductType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type\AddContent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{   
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(
            SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
        );
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render(
        'AcmeTaskBundle:Default:login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
  }
public function panelAction(Request $request)
{   

}
public function loginCheckAction()
  { 

    return new Response('true');

  }
```

and login.html.twig is

```
{# src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig #}
{% if error %}
  <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

 <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

{#
    If you want to control the URL the user is redirected to on success (more details      below)
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
   #}

 <button type="submit">login</button>
 </form>
```

What should i put in login check.controller...if someone have complete login example in   symfony 2.1 plz put it in answer..

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997233/unable-to-find-the-controller-for-path-login-check/13997744#13997744 your login_check should not point to any controller and should be path within firewall pattern. It is path used internally by security system, but have to be defined as route as well so we can use twig `path` function for example

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a controller for the login_check . Symfony already defined its functions in default. I think you wouldn't wanna mess with it. If you want to perform actions after login , you can define it on a service etc.

this might help
[Symfony2: After successful login event, perform set of actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180351/symfony2-after-successful-login-event-perform-set-of-actions)