# Symfony 2.7.7. logout: unable to find controller for path /logout

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, logout

In a Symfony 2.7.7 project, I implemented a traditional login form as described in the official documentation. Unfortunately, I get the following error every time the user logout:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/logout". The route is wrongly configured.

I followed this configuration http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/security.html#logging-out and I did it successfully many times in the past but I can't find the error.

Here you are my code:

```
#security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false    
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            anonymous: ~
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check    
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login: ~
            remember_me:
                key: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 604800
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/utenti/modifica-password-scaduta, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/aziende, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_PERSONNEL, ROLE_DOCTOR] }
        - { path: ^/pazienti, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_PERSONNEL, ROLE_DOCTOR] }
        - { path: ^/cartelle-sanitarie, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_PERSONNEL, ROLE_DOCTOR] }

#routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

logout:
    path: /logout
```

The logout path is included in the list provided by router:debug

> Name                                    Method   Scheme Host Path
>    login_route                             ANY      ANY    ANY  /login
>    login_check                             ANY      ANY    ANY  /login_check
>   logout                                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /logout

I'm aware that many discussions are focused on this problem (i.e. http://www.forosdelweb.com/f68/symfony-2-7-logout-fallo-1133307/ or http://ambracode.com/index/show/99164) but I can't find the error from many days and I'm stuck!

Thank you

**UPDATE:** I have temporary fixed it defining a logout action in the SecurityController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
    $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(null);

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login_route'));
}
```

Maybe this code can help someone who is in my same conditions!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you're trying to match /logout.
You have a prefix in your path (secured_area).
Try to use this pattern in secured_area:

```
pattern: ^/secured_area
```

Try to match this in your router.yml :

```
/secured_area/logout
```

Comment: same problem: "Unable to find the controller for path "/secured_area/logout". The route is wrongly configured.". I have edited my post with the result of router:debug as you requested before. Thanks

Comment: Try to watch this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409998/symfony2-1-unable-to-find-the-controller-for-path-login-check

Comment: Already seen... but I have not a prefix in my pattern. It seems a bit different or maybe I'm just not understanding how to fix the problem...

Comment: @Gianluca78 - did you ever figure this out?